# WPF Application - Not able to change rectangle properties on MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple WPF application which is a window application. There is a Canvas on this window. What I want to do is when I move the mouse on the Canvas It should draw a rectangle on the canvas and next when I press the left mouse button the color of the rectangle should get changed. I am perfectly able to draw a rectangle on mouse move event and also receiving MouseDown event on Rectangle but when I am trying to change the color of this rectangle It is not working. The code is very simple

Here is my xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="#11FFFFFF"  IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="overlay" Opacity="1">

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is my xaml.cs file

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            overlay.MouseMove += OnOverlayMouseMove;
        }

        private void OnOverlayMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            overlay.Children.Clear();

            Point ps = args.GetPosition(overlay);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = Brushes.LightBlue,
                Stroke = Brushes.LightGray,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Width = 100,
                Height = 50
            };

            rect.Opacity = 0.5;
            rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown;
            rect.Name = "Blue";

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, ps.X - 50);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, ps.Y - 25);
            overlay.Children.Add(rect);
        }

        private void OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

            if (rect.Name.Equals("Blue"))
            {
                rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
                rect.Name = "Black";
            }
            else
            {
                rect.Fill = Brushes.LightBlue;
                rect.Name = "Blue";
            }

            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, you shouldn't clear the Canvas and create a new Rectangle on every mouse move. That's extremely inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

The color is not changing because you are creating a new rectangle every time OnOverlayMouseMove is called and setting Fill to LightBlue

You can do something like the following,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            overlay.MouseMove += OnOverlayMouseMove;
        }

        private void OnOverlayMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            overlay.Children.Clear();

            Point ps = args.GetPosition(overlay);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = brush,
                Stroke = Brushes.LightGray,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Width = 100,
                Height = 50
            };

            rect.Opacity = 0.5;
            rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown;
            rect.Name = "Blue";

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, ps.X - 50);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, ps.Y - 25);
            overlay.Children.Add(rect);
        }
        private SolidColorBrush brush = Brushes.LightBlue;
        private void OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

            if (brush == Brushes.LightBlue)
            {
                brush = Brushes.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                brush = Brushes.LightBlue;
            }

            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No It is not working...you please try first at your end

Comment: My objective is not just to change the color of the rectangle but also change some the properties of this rectangle...

Comment: Think you forgot to include the code for not creating a new rectangle everytime.

Comment: `Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;` does not create a new Rectangle. Please take a closer look at the question.

Comment: I said in OnOverlayMouseMove he is creating a new rectangle please read the answer carefully

Comment: @ZubairAhmad I tried it before posting it and it is working.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Color normal = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
    private Color active = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);

    private SolidColorBrush rectangleBrush;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rectangleBrush = new SolidColorBrush(normal);
        overlay.MouseMove += OnOverlayMouseMove;
    }

    private void OnOverlayMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        overlay.Children.Clear();

        Point ps = args.GetPosition(overlay);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = rectangleBrush,
            Stroke = Brushes.LightGray,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Width = 100,
            Height = 50
        };

        rect.Opacity = 0.5;
        rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown;

        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, ps.X - 50);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, ps.Y - 25);
        overlay.Children.Add(rect);
    }

    private void OnRectLeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

        if ((rect.Fill as SolidColorBrush).Color == normal) {
            rectangleBrush.Color = active;
        } else {
            rectangleBrush.Color = normal;
        }

        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

If you want use colors from Color struct just replace normal and active vars with "Colors.LightBlue" and "Colors.Black"